# 150cm X 25cm ceramic tiles - how to cut them?

Tags: bathroom, tile, ceramic-tile, cutting

I have wood-look large ceramic tiles for my bathroom and I don't know how to cut them without damaging.
While it was easy with smaller format tiles, cutting these alongside does make me worry that the tile might snap.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Wet tile saw

[image: wet tile saw]

The best way to cut straight lines is to use a wet tile saw. This gives you a nice clean line, and is safer and significantly less messy than a dry saw because the water keeps bits from flying everywhere.

### Snap tile cutter

[image: snap tile cutter]

Another option is a snap tile cutter. This scores the tile and then you can snap it easily. It doesn't produce as clean of cuts as a wet saw so it's an ok option if you are hiding the cut edge under baseboard at the edges of the room.

### Tile nipper

[image: tile nipper]

Another option is a tile nipper. These are only for cutting small pieces, doing detail work or cutting curves. They literally nibble a way a little bit at a time.

Comment: have you cut tiles of this size yourself? And thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Marek - The wet tile saw is the way to go for cutting the large size tiles like you have. Often a good choice is to rent a tile saw for a day so you do not have to purchase the saw outright.

Comment: @michael-karas What'd be the minimum size (table size) of such wet tile saw you'd recommend to rent?

Comment: One that can handle the maximum length of cut you anticipate making.